# Django urlpatterns

Tags: python, django, url

Возникла проблема,у меня есть есть три приложения: blog, bloger, blog1. 
blog - главная страница сайта, bloger - blog , blog1 - книги. 
Так уж получилось, что нужно добавить переходы между этими приложениями blog <->bloger <-> blog1. 
Но возникает проблема, при проектировании urlов в url.py:

```
url(r'^bloger/', include('bloger.urls')),
```

ссылка на bloger с главной страницы. Помогите переделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос конечно сформулирован весьма витиевато но вроде у тебя должно получиться что то вроде этого:

```
url(r'^', include('blog.urls', name='home')),    
url(r'^bloger/', include('bloger.urls'), name='bloger'),
url(r'^blog1/', include('blog1.urls'), name='bloger1'),
```

После этого в шаблонах можешь указывать в качестве ссылки

```
href={% url 'home' %}
```

Так же в каждом приложении у тебя соответственно должен быть свой urls.py.

Собственно если не угадал с ответом то переформулируй вопрос.

Comment: Что делать, если я добавил урлы, но темплэйт не может найти, хотя путь во вьюхе правильный. Ошибка : TemplateDoesNotExist at /bloger/. Код: return render(request, 'bloger/blog_list.html', {})

Comment: Темплейт должен лежать по следующему пути bloger/templates/bloger/blog_list.html . Во въезде путь так и оставляешь bloger/blog_list.html

Comment: ошибка все та же

Comment: Ну т огда описывай нормально, Пиши где что у тебя лежит: Где вьюха из которй вызываешь? где шаблоны? прям полные пути давай, и структуру проекта

Comment: вьюха находится из которой вызываю: TEZLA/Tezla/bloger/views.py . шаблоны находятся в каждом приложении , под папкой templates. напр. TEZLA/Tezla/blog/tamplates/blog/post_list.html .

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть так

```
TEZLA
    ├───bloger
    |        ├───templates
    |        |      └───bloger
    |        |              └─── post_list.html
    |        ├──views.py
    |        ├──models.py.py
    |
    ├───manage.py
    └───Tezla
              settings.py
              urls.py
              wsgi.py
              __init__.py
```